# Possible to specify csv delimiter for writing?

Tags: python

Is it possible to specify the delimiting character the csv module will use when writing a file?

For example, instead of ',' use ';' or something?

I know you can change to tab delimited by setting `dialect='excel-tab`, but not sure if there is an option for freely choosing the delimiter.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can just set the [`delimiter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters):

```
writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=';')
```

There's also an example of this in the documentation for [`csv.writer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)